# python marshmallow force field.int to only accept int and not strings

Tags: python, int, marshmallow

I have a marshmallow integer field, but very strange when I pass the data 
as {number:"123"}  also works,  as if was an integer,  I would assume that internally is making the conversion to int,  but don't want that  I want to force the user to use INT all the time so there is no confusion of what data types can accept,  is there a way or parameter for that?

```
number = fields.Integer(required=True,
                        validate=Range(min=1, error="Value must be greater than 0"))
```

thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 12):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/dev/marshmallow/fields.py#L668) I think it's not possible, and I'm surprised by that. I know there is a *strict* flag you can set, but it only operates in certain cases. Observe:

```
from marshmallow import *
from  marshmallow.validate import Range

class MySchema(Schema):
    number = fields.Integer(strict=True, required=True, validate=[Range(min=1, error="Value must be greater than 0")])
```

It works in this case:

```
s = MySchema()
s.dumps({'number': "123.1"})
>>> MarshalResult(data='{}', errors={'number': ['Not a valid integer.']})
```

But not in these case

```
s.dumps({'number': 123.1})
>>> MarshalResult(data='{"number": 123}', errors={})

s.dumps({'number': "123"})
>>> MarshalResult(data='{"number": 123}', errors={})
```

Which I find inconsistent. Perhaps your best bet is writing either a [custom field](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_fields.html#custom-fields) or a different validator that validates the input before it's passed to your schema.

**Update:**
Looks like the issue is fixed in recent versions of Marshmallow

Comment: yes,  we found that only works from float to int,  and is been converted as soon it gets to the marshmallow.validate(dict),  we even try a custom validation on the field, but is already converted before getting to the validations per field =(,   I was thinking that strict means,  you can only and ONLY pass ints and nothing else.

Comment: I think what you said, was in fact the intended behavior. This looks like a bug to me. I'll open an issue for this on github.

Comment: thanks, I appreciated,  I didn't know that was possible to report the bug like that.   =)

Comment: @pelos: Looks like this is a known issue. If you are interested see https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/pull/755

Answer (score 6):

If you read this now, setting `strict=True` on the field will work